# What is <T> in dynamic forms?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Im following the Angular2 cookbook recipe for [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html).  It calls for

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
value: T,
...
```

I cant seem to find out what the  is doing in both spots.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are so called "Generics". You may just google for the term "generics", for example in combination with "typescript", in order to get a more detailed answer.

The quick version is: 
with generics you do not care which type T is - as long as it is the same type everywhere you use it.
So an instance of

```
QuestionBase<String>
```

has to make sure that the property "value" is of type String

Comment: Gotcha! So is it analogous to an argument you can pass into a function? But instead of a function, its an array? Hope that makes sense...

Comment: hm i don't really get your analogy. you are not passing any arguments, you are just defining of which type T will be. for QuestionBase<String>, T will be String. for QuestionBase<Foo>, T will be Foo

Comment: Thanks! Im still learning Angular/JS, and I have to use analogies for somethings to stick in my head. I didn't mean argument in the same sense as in a function, just that its a placeholder for something not yet known. Only when you create an instance of that object, the property of  the "value"  is then defined.

Answer (score 3):

The `T` on the `QuestionBase<T>` stands for `Type`. 
This means that whatever type you enter in the `<>` that is the type that `value` will have.
So,
If `T = string`:

```
export class QuestionBase<string>{
value: string,
```

If `T = int`:

```
export class QuestionBase<int>{
value: int,
```

If `T = any`:

```
export class QuestionBase<any>{
value: any,
```

If `T = any[]`:

```
export class QuestionBase<any[]>{
value: any[],
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` here makes your class a template..which means your class can be of any type

while creating the object of QuestionBase you can say like below

```
var obj=new  QuestionBase<string>();
```

now here your value property will be of string type.

Similarly

`var obj=new  QuestionBase<int>();` value property will of type int here.

Comment: Thanks to you and @PatrickKelleter. You both deserve the answer